# ERROR: syntax error at or near "SET"

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error, sql

```
   UPDATE m_price
   SET pricelist=15.159, pricestd=14.3184
   WHERE m_product_id = 1000332
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SET" i am getting this error in POSTGRESQL.

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE m_price (
m_pricelist_version_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
m_product_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
ad_client_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
ad_org_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
isactive character(1) DEFAULT 'Y'::bpchar NOT NULL,
created timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
createdby numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
updated timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
updatedby numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
pricelist numeric DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
pricestd numeric DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
pricelimit numeric DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT m_productprice_isactive_check CHECK ((isactive = ANY (ARRAY['Y'::bpchar,  'N'::bpchar])))
       );
```

Comment: What code is before this please?

Comment: just trying to update directly in the sql

Comment: Verify the spelling of your fieldnames. And make sure that their fieldtypes are set to float.

Comment: Please post the table definition.

Comment: Works for me... try copying your query from here and try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE m_price
SET (pricelist,pricestd)=(15.159,14.3184)
WHERE m_product_id = 1000332
```